# CSS background-size-x property?

Tags: width, css

I am trying to set the width of a background image -- without modifying the height of said image. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Prior to CSS3

To have full control of the background image you could create a div with a really low `z-index` and `position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0;` to make everything float above it.

If you don't want to hard code the height of your image you'll need to use javascript to do the stretching, otherwise it will just scale according to the ratio between *width* and *height*.

---

#### CSS3

In [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) you can use the property `background-size`, but it's the same thing here.. you'll need to use javascript if you don't want the image to scale according to the ratio between *width* and *height*.

Answer (score 15):

The selected answer is wrong, I think. You **can** do it using pure CSS 3 only, using `background-size: 100% auto` for an auto-inferred height or `background-size: auto 100%` for an auto-inferred width. The ratio will remain constant. Only if you use `background-size: 100% 100%` (abbreviated as `background-size: 100%`) does the ratio change.

Comment: this just solved an annoying bug in my react app - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the timthumb library - it can crop images which can achieve what you need. You need to install tim thumb (e.g. timthumb.php) and then change your image to point at your timthumb page and pass through the html encoded url of the image. It processes it, makes it the width you need without modifying the height of the image.